# Azure Batch - Setting custom user identity for tasks

Tags: azure-batch

I am using Azure Batch C# Client API 6.1.  I am trying to have all my runs using the same user identity.

I am setting a custom user identity as below, as per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.protocol.models.cloudtask.useridentity?view=azurebatch-6.1.0) documentation.

```
var task = new CloudTask("{guid}", "command string")
{
    DisplayName = "display name",
    UserIdentity = new UserIdentity("customUserid")
}
```

However when the job runs, the task executes under a random user account.

Would anyone know how to make it work OR even if it is supported by the backend Azure Batch service?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use named user accounts, you need to first specify a list of [UserAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.protocol.models.useraccount?view=azurebatch-6.1.0) on your [CloudPool during creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.protocol.models.cloudpool.useraccounts?view=azurebatch-6.1.0#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_Protocol_Models_CloudPool_UserAccounts).

```
pool.UserAccounts = new List<UserAccount>
{
    new UserAccount("myadminaccount", "adminpassword", ElevationLevel.Admin),
    new UserAccount("mynonadminaccount", "nonadminpassword", ElevationLevel.NonAdmin),
};
```

You will then be able to execute tasks assigned to this pool with `UserIdentity` properties as you have in your example.

Unfortunately the MSDN documentation for this feature is lagging behind currently, but should be updated soon.