# Azure Batch :Elevating the user privileges during Pool Creation using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli, azure-batch

I need to mount the azure file storage to Linux-Pools when they are being spun-up.I am following the instructions given here to achieve that: [mounting Azure-File Storage to Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/pool-file-shares) Specically in my Azure CLI script under the Pools start commands I am inserting something which looks like this

```
--start-task-command-line="apt-get update && apt-get install cifs-utils && mkdir -p {} && mount -t cifs {} {} -o vers=3.0,username={},password={},dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino".format(_COMPUTE_NODE_MOUNT_POINT, _STORAGE_ACCOUNT_SHARE_ENDPOINT, _COMPUTE_NODE_MOUNT_POINT, _STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, _STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY)
```

but when I run the tasks with the auto-user that batch uses by default I get an error in the stderr.txt file mentioning that it was unable to create the "/mnt/MyAzureFileshare" directory and so my guess is the mounting didn't occur during the pool creation process.I saw a very similar question to the one I am  facing:[setting custom user identity for tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384286/azure-batch-setting-custom-user-identity-for-tasks) and even the official Microsoft documentation goes over this in detail:[Run Tasks under User accounts in Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-user-accounts) but none of them put a light on how to achieve this using Azure CLI.

In order to install specific packages so that Azure File Storage can be mounted requires sudo privileges and I am unable to do that through the Azure-CLI. In order to recreate the error I would recommend having a look at this:[app to replicate the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815687/unable-to-run-tasks-on-azure-batchnodes-go-into-unusable-state-after-starting-u)

What I want to achieve is:

**1) Create a Pool with the Azure-File Storage mounted on it and elevate the privileges of the auto-user to the admin level using Azure CLI**

**2) Run tasks with the same auto-user with Admin Privileges using the azure CLI**

**Update 1:**
I was able to mount Azure File Storage with Batch using the Azure CLI. I still am not able to populate the Azure File Storage with the output files of the app that I deployed on Batch Nodes.I have got no error in the stderr.txt files.
The output of the stderr.txt file is:

```
WARNING: In "login" auth mode, the following arguments are ignored: --account-key

Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%

pdf--->png:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
pdf--->png: 100%|##########| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  1.16it/s]WARNING: In "login" auth mode, the following arguments are ignored: --account-key
WARNING: uploading /mnt/batch/tasks/workitems/pdf-processing-job-2018-10-29-15-36-15/job-1/mytask-0/wd/png_files-2018-10-29-15-39-25/akronbeaconjournal_20180108_AkronBeaconJournal_0___page---0.png

Alive[################################################################]  100.0000%
Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
```

The Python App that was deployed on the Batch Nodes is:

```
import os
import fitz
import subprocess
import argparse
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
import sentry_sdk
import sys
import datetime

def azure_active_directory_login(azure_username,azure_password,azure_tenant):
    try:
        azure_login_output=subprocess.check_output(["az","login","--service-principal","--username",azure_username,"--password",azure_password,"--tenant",azure_tenant])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        sentry_sdk.capture_message("Invalid Azure Login Credentials")
        sys.exit("Invalid Azure Login Credentials")

def download_from_azure_blob(azure_storage_account,azure_storage_account_key,input_azure_container,file_to_process,pdf_docs_path):
    file_to_download=os.path.join(input_azure_container,file_to_process)
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(["az","storage","blob","download","--container-name",input_azure_container,"--file",os.path.join(pdf_docs_path,file_to_process),"--name",file_to_process,"--account-key",azure_storage_account_key,\
        "--account-name",azure_storage_account,"--auth-mode","login"])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        sentry_sdk.capture_message("unable to download the pdf file")
        sys.exit("unable to download the pdf file")

def pdf_to_png(input_folder_path,output_folder_path):
    pdf_files=[x for x in os.listdir(input_folder_path) if x.endswith((".pdf",".PDF"))]
    pdf_files.sort()
    for pdf in tqdm(pdf_files,desc="pdf--->png"):
        doc=fitz.open(os.path.join(input_folder_path,pdf))
        page_count=doc.pageCount
        for f in range(page_count):
            page=doc.loadPage(f)
            pix = page.getPixmap()
            if pdf.endswith(".pdf"):
                png_filename=pdf.split(".pdf")[0]+"___"+"page---"+str(f)+".png"
                pix.writePNG(os.path.join(output_folder_path,png_filename))
            elif pdf.endswith(".PDF"):
                png_filename=pdf.split(".PDF")[0]+"___"+"page---"+str(f)+".png"
                pix.writePNG(os.path.join(output_folder_path,png_filename))


def upload_to_azure_blob(azure_storage_account,azure_storage_account_key,output_azure_container,png_docs_path):
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(["az","storage","blob","upload-batch","--destination",output_azure_container,"--source",png_docs_path,"--account-key",azure_storage_account_key,\
        "--account-name",azure_storage_account,"--auth-mode","login"])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        sentry_sdk.capture_message("Unable to upload file to the container")

def upload_to_fileshare(png_docs_path):
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(["cp","-r",png_docs_path,"/mnt/MyAzureFileShare/"])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        sentry_sdk.capture_message("unable to upload to azure file share ")

if __name__=="__main__":
    #Credentials 
    sentry_sdk.init("<Sentry Creds>")
    azure_username=<azure_username>
    azure_password=<azure_password>
    azure_tenant=<azure_tenant>
    azure_storage_account=<azure_storage_account>
    azure_storage_account_key=<azure_account_key>
    try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("input_azure_container",type=str,help="Location to download files from")
        parser.add_argument("output_azure_container",type=str,help="Location to upload files to")
        parser.add_argument("file_to_process",type=str,help="file link in azure blob storage")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        timestamp = time.time()
        timestamp_humanreadable= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
        task_working_dir=os.getcwd()
        file_to_process=args.file_to_process
        input_azure_container=args.input_azure_container
        output_azure_container=args.output_azure_container
        pdf_docs_path=os.path.join(task_working_dir,"pdf_files"+"-"+timestamp_humanreadable)
        png_docs_path=os.path.join(task_working_dir,"png_files"+"-"+timestamp_humanreadable)
        os.mkdir(pdf_docs_path)
        os.mkdir(png_docs_path)
    except Exception as e:
        sentry_sdk.capture_exception(e)
    azure_active_directory_login(azure_username,azure_password,azure_tenant)
    download_from_azure_blob(azure_storage_account,azure_storage_account_key,input_azure_container,file_to_process,pdf_docs_path)
    pdf_to_png(pdf_docs_path,png_docs_path)
    upload_to_azure_blob(azure_storage_account,azure_storage_account_key,output_azure_container,png_docs_path)
    upload_to_fileshare(png_docs_path)
```

The upload_to_fileshare() in the python app above should initiate the upload but in my case nothing happens and there is no error in the copy operation in the stderr.txt files

**Please let me know a way to troubleshoot this issue**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like the run elevated parameter is exposed via a command line argument through the CLI.  You can however specify a JSON file to the --json argument formatted as the REST API object to get all functionalities.

Comment: Seeing as you are using a Python script using the Batch and Storage SDK's should give you more verbose errors, should anything have gone wrong with one of your calls.